# ZSH not finding commands

Tags: macos, command-line, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've noticed several times that `zsh` can't find commands when running pipes, e.g.:

```
➜  ~  ps aux | grep terminal
zsh: command not found:  grep
➜  ~  curl -L https://raw.github.com/zaiste/vimified/master/install.sh | sh
zsh: command not found: sh
```

There's no trouble calling these commands regularly. I'm using zsh 5.0.4 and oh-my-zsh on Mac OS X 10.8.3.

The above works in `bash`.

This is my `.zshrc`:

```
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
plugins=(git brew)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

Comment: Please show your `zshrc`. Does it work without oh-my-zsh and a plain (default) `zshrc`?

Comment: It's the same with a plain `.zshrc`.

Comment: I have a suspicion. If you copy and paste this part here: `ps aux | grep terminal`, does it work?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly.

Comment: Let me know if the solution linked to above works for you. You will probably keep pressing ⌥ with the space (because you need it for the pipe character), after which OS X inserts a non-breaking space instead of the usual.

Comment: The solution you linked works perfectly, thanks! As for the second part of my question - should I post a new question and remove that part from this one?

Comment: Yes, please do that :)